# Microservices message broker in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, microservices

What is the most efficient **message broker** to be used for developing **Microservices** in **Asp .NET Core**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use RabbitMQ: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html

Comment: Ok I will check that... thanks